# Setting caps lock key to CTRL but still function as caps lock if I press for long enough in Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, vim, keyboard, tmux, modifier-keys

If possible I would like something similar to this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/4815/31313

Basically a simple script that detects when I'm in `tmux`, if I am change the CAPS lock key to be a CTRL key, else revert it.

However it is also important for me to use the CAPS lock key from time to time, in those occasions I would like to keep it pressed for 5 seconds, then it triggers a normal CAPS lock.

Would this be easy to do? Possible to do? I would prefer if I don't use any kind of extra software so that I can just put this in a script.

**Extra info:**

I would want to achieve this in a Mac Mini with OSX Snow Leopard, if possible also with Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already changed caps lock to control, adding this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook would make holding control (or caps lock) toggle caps lock:

`<autogen>--HoldingKeyToKey-- KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK, Option::NOREPEAT</autogen>`

The threshold for holding keys is 0.2 s by default, but it can be changed in the second tab.

(I suggested changing fn+control (fn+caps lock) to caps lock in the [previous question at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76291/setting-caps-lock-key-to-ctrl-but-still-function-as-caps-lock-if-i-press-for-lon):)

`<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CONTROL_L, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK</autogen>`

If you just want to keep some key as caps lock, you can also change control to caps lock in System Preferences.

Comment: So, I would add `<only>TERMINAL</only>` after the autogen statement? Or inside it? Would this also work if iTerm is used instead of the Terminal app? Thanks for the tip, although I don't have an fn key with this keyboard (it's a couple of generations of iMac back), you think that would work if I did <kbd>Option+Shift+Caps lock</kbd> instead?

Comment: Before or after it. But `<only>TERMINAL</only>` is just Terminal.app, and there's no constant for iTerm. For option and shift, change `ModifierFlag::FN` to `VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT`.

Comment: OK, so I use `<autogen>--HoldingKeyToKey-- KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::VK_NONE, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK, Option::NOREPEAT</autogen><only>TERMINAL</only>` if I want the functionality I requested in the post, after changing the holding key threshold. And I would `<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CONTROL_L, VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK</autogen><only>TERMINAL</only>` if I want to remap caps lock to CTRL and press <kbd>Option+Shift+Caps lock</kbd> to switch caps lock. Right?

Comment: If you wanted caps lock to function as caps lock outside Terminal, you'd need to use [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) to change caps lock to something like F19 and then remap F19.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! Although this does solve it, it doesn't do it with a script so I won't accept it, but it's definitely a workaround. Thanks for looking into this. :)